# Set table td height and overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I want to display a vertical scrollbar on the `td` when its contents are exceeding a specified height of the row.

I have [this](http://jsbin.com/ixetu/87/edit) sample code but it does not display active scrollbar on y axis no matter the content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Browsers won't apply overflow scrollbars to `TD` tags. You will need to enclose the content of your table cells in a `div` tag, and scroll that:

```
<td><div>Do you see what I meancxzdaaaaaaaaaaaaa?</div></td>
```

and:

```
td > div { overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: Thanks, just to add that you have to specify the desired div height in order to display the scrollbar correctly.

Answer (score 5):

`Overflow:scroll;` should give a scroll bar on a block level element, which `td` is not. What should it do on a `td` ? The CSS spec is not clear on this, so browser behavior differs.

Chrome will apply a scroll bar, but FF and IE won't. For a cross-browser solution, you can add an extra container div and apply the CSS to that instead though.

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      table { width:250px;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse }
      table tr { height:1em;  }
      td > div { overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>This is a test.</td>
        <td><div>Do you see what I meancxzdaaaaaaaaaaaaa?</div></td>
        <td>I hate this overflow.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
td > div { overflow-y:auto;}
```

This will add the vertical scroll bar when needed.